# how to set a position of one div relative to another div?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set position of one DIV element  relative to another DIV element which do not have any parent-child relationship?

Comment: Please show us the code you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible to do so with just **css**.

It can be achieved using **javascript** or by using JQuery UI Framework. **[*JQuery UI/Position*](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)**

```
$("#my_div").position({
  my:        "left top",
  at:        "left bottom",
  of:        this, // or $("#otherdiv")
  collision: "fit"
})
```